# E/I inductive position transducer sensing device operation

Tags: current, transformer, ac, servo

I have been doing some research on AC servo position flight control surface systems and was trying to find the component used to set the pilot's input command. Found out that an E/I inductive position transducer sensing device is used. I know briefly how it operates. It consists of 2 magnetic cores with a movable shunting bar, and the voltage output depends on the position of said bar. Can anyone explain in detail how pilots use this device to set their commands for flight control surfaces?

[image]

Comment: Are you asking what is the mechanical interface between the pilot's hand and the shunting bar?

Comment: Yes, basically.

Comment: That might not constitute a valid question for this site.

Comment: Any idea where I can get an answer for this question?

Comment: [Aviation](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/) or [Engineering](https://engineering.stackexchange.com/) SEs ?

Answer (score 1):

What you are referring to is a displacement sensor known as an LVDT or Linear Variable Differential Transformer. When the core is centralised, the output is zero. Displacing the core in one direction gives a variable output that is in phase with the excitation whereas displacing it in the opposite direction gives a variable output that is out of phase with the excitation. A positive variable DC output in one direction and a negative one in the opposite direction is the result of further processing.

[image]

The LVDT is used as the feedback element, in a closed loop servo-controlled system, to stop movement when the commanded position is reached.

A pilot's flight control command only outputs a control voltage to the servo system. He does not physically interface with the LVDT.